# Mail from AOL, font to small Fix?

Tags: macos, mail.app

I know that Mavericks removed the PreferPlainText preference, but I have a client that uses AOL and must use the web-client that always created HTML formatted emails with a text size of 10px....

I get a lot of email from her... Is there a way to fix this?

I've not up'd to Yosemite yet... Anyone know if its different there?

thanks!

Comment: is that in Apple Mail or a AOL app on Mac ? Apple mail in mavericks still has the Plain Text option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think Mavericks Mail has only "Raw Source" and then you get a new window and are looking at all the rubbish HTML...previous to Mavericks there was a hidden pref you could set to PreferPlainText = yes...

Answer (score 1):

Command Shift + will increase the font-size while viewing an email.